# Electromechanical connection for lamp

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I need help with a project and would appreciate any advice or recommendations you can provide. I'll do my best to explain my concept and the issue I'm facing. Concept: I have a pad with a heavy section, designed to hold a PCB with an on/off switch and other functions for a desk lamp. The desk lamp itself can be easily attached and detached from the pad since there are various lamp types available. I'm seeking advice on the mechanical and electrical connections. Mechanical Connection: I'm thinking of using a screw thread on the pad for stability, making it easy for anyone to attach and detach the lamp. The challenge is incorporating the electrical connection into this mechanical setup. If this proves too difficult, I might resort to an external wire for the electrical connection, though it's not my preferred design. Do you know of any connectors that combine both mechanical and electrical connections? If not, is it feasible to design one? I've attached some photos of the mechanical design to help illustrate my idea, as I find it challenging to explain in words. I appreciate your time and any assistance you can offer. Thank you!
[image: link]

Comment: I can't see the images.

Comment: how is the desk lamp powered? ... if it is line voltage, then you are limited to legal connections only

Comment: Every electric outlet's plug combines mechanical and electric connections.  They need to not fall out after all.  They just take different amounts of load.  There are some that twist lock as well.  What you need depends on the power and loads.

Comment: Thank you for adding the image. USB C PD inside a hole for max interoperability.  If it were a lot bigger, you could go with a car's "cigarette lighter" for that.  If you want to keep it simple, use a barrel jack, preferably the same variety as plugs into your input.